# What does this keychain say?

Tags: translation, kanji

I got this keychain for Christmas without any packaging so I have no idea what it means.

[image: Keychain]

The only thing I can tell is that it is probably a single kanji character, other than that I can't tell.

Comment: Have you actually been told that this was meant to be Japanese?  In the Japanese-speaking world (of which I am a member), it is NOT the kind of kanji one would make a keychain out of .  In the "other" kanji-using world, however, it would make a good keychain that makes sense.

Comment: @職場恋愛小説執筆中 It was probably intended to be Japanese, because I am very much a fan of Japan, but it might have been mistakenly purchased under the guise that they thought it was Japanese.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should belong to Chinese forums.

Comment: The migration was rejected since, although it *was* about Chinese, it was an off-topic translation question.  We should be careful only to migrate when the question fits the rules of the target site.  Here's a link to the Chinese.SE copy of the question: http://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/16846/2651

Answer (score 3):

It looks like 發 (old form of 発).

But I don't think that has any particularly profound meaning so why it would become a keychain...

> 發
>   (uncommon “Hyōgai” kanji, kyūjitai kanji, shinjitai form 発)
>   set off; depart; start from; emit; discharge; disclose; occur
>   https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%99%BC#Japanese

Comment: 「溌剌」(vivid, energetic)などからの連想ですかね？

Comment: I'm certain it's more likely to be Chinese, where 發 has a particular meaning as in the Chinese New Year formulaic greeting 恭喜發財 -- to get rich.

Comment: @jogloran Ah that makes sense. If they don't respond to 職場恋愛小説執筆中 asking if it's really Japanese soon, I guess we should close this as off-topic?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is 發, which is the traditional form of 発.